# How to change the value of an attribute in a new XML document?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

I have a database where is a ton of XML file who's waiting to get update. The update would wipe ALL files in the database. Each new file would be the same as his previous except for the attribute value.

But I want to keep each attributes `type` that have `session` as value. This attribute is in each file multiple time. But, it's doesn't work for the moment: attributes doesn't update at all).

> How can I change the value of an specific attribute in an new XML file identical depending of another one?

This is what I did so far...

So I decided to find a way to get the path to these attributes using this code for each file before the wipe:

```
List<XmlList> dBPathTypeSession = new List<XmlList>();
/*reader*/
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(sessionType.Parameters);

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

//I think my problem come from this line below
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//node()[@type='session']");

dBPathTypeSession.Add(new XmlList("b_session_type", i, nodes));//table,row,paths
```

> The code below this line is probably not needed to answer my question, this is just more detail.

And then correct the attributes value after the update with this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(sessionType.Parameters);

foreach (XmlNode node in file.Paths)//XmlList file = new XmlList();
{
    if (node.Attributes["type"].Value == "system")
    {
        node.Attributes["type"].Value = "session";
    }
}
//push to DB
```

The informations for every path in each file is contain in this:

```
//But I think this is pointless for my question
public class XmlList
{
    public XmlList(string tablePath, int filePath, XmlNodeList paths)
    {
        this.TablePath = tablePath;
        this.FilePath = filePath;
        this.Paths = paths;
    }
    public string TablePath {get; private set;}
    public int FilePath {get; private set;}
    public XmlNodeList Paths {get;set;}
}
```

I'm using C# 3.0(`.NET framework 3.5`), I MUST use `XMLDocument` to make it fit with everything else in the code.

Here's an example of what the `XML` look like before update(short version)

```
<Session is_hidden="false">
    <ID is_static="true">1</ID>
    <SESSIONIDX is_static="true">0</SESSIONIDX>
    <Timing>
        <FirstPresentation display_name="FirstPresentation" type="system"/>
        <Pause display_name="Pause" type="system" datatype="float"/>
        <Feedback display_name="Feedback" type="session" datatype="float"/>
        <Answer display_name="Answer" type="system" datatype="float"/>
    </Timing>
    <Balls>
        <Indexed display_name="Indexed" type="session" datatype="pos_int"/>
        <IndexingColor1 display_name="IndexingColor1" type="system" datatype="list">
            <list>
                <ListItem>RED</ListItem>
                <ListItem>BLUE</ListItem>
            </list>
        </IndexingColor1>
    </Balls>
</Session>
```

Here's an example of what the `XML` look like after update(short version)

```
<Session is_hidden="false">
    <ID is_static="true">1</ID>
    <SESSIONIDX is_static="true">0</SESSIONIDX>
    <Timing>
        <FirstPresentation display_name="FirstPresentation" type="session"/>//system change for session
        <Pause display_name="Pause" type="system" datatype="float"/>
        <Feedback display_name="Feedback" type="system" datatype="float"/>//session change for system
        <Answer display_name="Answer" type="system" datatype="float"/>//system stay system
    </Timing>
    <Balls>
        <Indexed display_name="Indexed" type="session" datatype="pos_int"/>//session stay session
        <IndexingColor1 display_name="IndexingColor1" type="system" datatype="list">
            <list>
                <ListItem>RED</ListItem>
                <ListItem>BLUE</ListItem>
            </list>
        </IndexingColor1>
    </Balls>
</Session>
```

Here's an example of what the `XML` of what I'm looking for:

```
<Session is_hidden="false">
    <ID is_static="true">1</ID>
    <SESSIONIDX is_static="true">0</SESSIONIDX>
    <Timing>
        <FirstPresentation display_name="FirstPresentation" type="session"/>//system stay session
        <Pause display_name="Pause" type="system" datatype="float"/>
        <Feedback display_name="Feedback" type="session" datatype="float"/>//session return session
        <Answer display_name="Answer" type="system" datatype="float"/>//system stay system
    </Timing>
    <Balls>
        <Indexed display_name="Indexed" type="session" datatype="pos_int"/>//session stay session
        <IndexingColor1 display_name="IndexingColor1" type="system" datatype="list">
            <list>
                <ListItem>RED</ListItem>
                <ListItem>BLUE</ListItem>
            </list>
        </IndexingColor1>
    </Balls>
</Session>
```

If we compare this to boolean algebra, we have this :

> For x = session & y = system
>
> before update = after update -> What we want
>
> > x = x -> x
> >
> > x = y -> x
> >
> > y = x -> x
> >
> > y = y -> y

If you need more information just ask in comment and I will update the post.

Comment: This works when I'm not updating the `XML`. I think the problem come from the `SelecNodes`

Comment: Can you post an example of the XML?

Comment: Your code to modify the attributes of an XmlNode is in theory correct.  You can see this in the debugger by doing `Debug.WriteLine(doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml)` after making the modification.  So, either your XPath query isn't working, or the XML isn't what you think, or your "push to DB" isn't working.  If you show us the XML, we might be able to help further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are searching for nodes with an attribute named `type` with value `session` -- then replacing that value if the *current* value is `system`.  That's not going to work, since the value can't be both.

You must want either:

```
    foreach (XmlNode node in root.SelectNodes("//node()[@type='session']"))
        node.Attributes["type"].Value = "system";
```

or

```
    foreach (XmlNode node in root.SelectNodes("//node()[@type='system']"))
        node.Attributes["type"].Value = "session";
```

**Update**

If you have two `XmlDocuments` that have identical element hierarchies but different sets of attributes for each element, and wish to propagate some attribute information from the first to the second, you need to walk the element hierarchies and create temporary mapping tables between them.  The following does that, assuming the elements are corresponded by name, and then by order if duplicate names exist (e.g. in a list):

```
    static void WalkMatchingElements(XmlElement root1, XmlElement root2, Action<XmlElement, XmlElement> action)
    {
        WalkMatchingElements(root1, root2, (element) => (element.Name), action);
    }

    static void WalkMatchingElements<TKey>(XmlElement root1, XmlElement root2, Func<XmlElement, TKey> getKey, Action<XmlElement, XmlElement> action)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(getKey(root1), getKey(root2)))
            action(root1, root2);
        var children1GroupedByName = root1.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().GroupBy(getKey);
        var children2LookupByName = root2.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().ToLookup(getKey);
        foreach (var child1group in children1GroupedByName)
        {
            var child2group = children2LookupByName[child1group.Key];
            foreach (var pair in child1group.Zip(child2group, (el1, el2) => new KeyValuePair<XmlElement, XmlElement>(el1, el2)))
                WalkMatchingElements(pair.Key, pair.Value, getKey, action);
        }
    }
```

And then call it like:

```
        var oldDoc = new XmlDocument();
        oldDoc.LoadXml(oldXml);

        var newDoc = new XmlDocument();
        newDoc.LoadXml(newXml);

        WalkMatchingElements(oldDoc.DocumentElement, newDoc.DocumentElement, (elOld, elNew) =>
            {
                var attrOld = elOld.Attributes["type"];
                if (attrOld != null && attrOld.Value == "session")
                {
                    elNew.SetAttribute("type", "system");
                }
            });
```

**Update2** If you don't want the entire old `XmlDocument` in memory at once (though I don't see why not), you can built a lookup table of elements with a `type` attribute, indexed by path, then use that later:

```
    const string AttributeName = "type";

        var lookup = oldDoc.DocumentElement.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<XmlElement>().Where(el => el.HasAttribute(AttributeName)).ToLookup(el => el.Path(), el => el.Attributes[AttributeName].Value);

        // And then later

        WalkMatchingElements(new XmlElement[] { newDoc.DocumentElement }, lookup, (el, oldValue) =>
            {
                if (oldValue != null && oldValue == "session")
                    el.SetAttribute(AttributeName, "session");
            });


    private static void WalkMatchingElements<TValue>(IEnumerable<XmlElement> elements, ILookup<string, TValue> pathLookup, Action<XmlElement, TValue> action)
    {
        var elementsByPath = elements.GroupBy(el => el.Path());
        foreach (var elementsGroup in elementsByPath)
        {
            foreach (var pair in elementsGroup.Zip(pathLookup[elementsGroup.Key], (el, value) => new KeyValuePair<XmlElement, TValue>(el, value)))
                action(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            foreach (var element in elementsGroup)
                WalkMatchingElements(element.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>(), pathLookup, action);
        }
    }
```

You'll need the following extension methods:

```
public static class XmlNodeExtensions
{
    public static string Path(this XmlElement element)
    {
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return element.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<XmlElement>().Reverse().Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, el) => sb.Append("/").Append(el.Name)).ToString();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<XmlNode> AncestorsAndSelf(this XmlNode node)
    {
        for (; node != null; node = node.ParentNode)
            yield return node;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<XmlNode> DescendantsAndSelf(this XmlNode root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            yield break;
        yield return root;
        foreach (var child in root.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>())
            foreach (var subChild in child.DescendantsAndSelf())
                yield return subChild;
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    // Back ported from .Net 4.0
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        if (first == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("first");
        if (second == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("second");
        if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("resultSelector");
        return ZipIterator(first, second, resultSelector);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipIterator<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TFirst> e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
        using (IEnumerator<TSecond> e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
            while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
                yield return resultSelector(e1.Current, e2.Current);
    }
}
```

(I had forgotten that `Zip` is not in .Net 3.5.)

Comment: There will be an update that will wipe every `XML` and set a new file with the same nodes but different attributes value, so the two operations will not be on the same file. 1: I get the nodes path on the `XML` 2:Wipe all `XML`, 3:set value using nodes path

Comment: @AnthonyLiard - OK, I think I understand.  Can you give examples of both the old and new XML?  Are the elements in 1-1 correspondence by order, or must they be corresponded by name.

Comment: They will generally correspond by order, but sometimes not, so it must corresponded by name.

Comment: child1.zip is suppose to mean what?

Comment: @AnthonyLiard - [`child1.zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) means "group the elements by name, and if there are any duplicates, walk then in pairs by original file order".

Comment: Do you have any ideaabout how to do this without a comparaison? The first `XML` and the second one doesn't exist at the same time, so the comparaison can't work except if I create dynamically my first `XML` files. This method is bit too heavy

Comment: @AnthonyLiard - updated the delegate passed to `Walk` based on your update table.  Also clarified some variable names hopefully making the code more transparent.  Doing this without the old XML is nontrivial because XML is a [tree](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp).  You need to recursively descend the new tree matching nodes by name with only those nodes at the equivalent location in the other tree.

Comment: I found the problem with my solution: `SelectNodes` create objects of the current file, so using these in another file will make not be possible. But the path as a string would be, I'm creating a function to generate the string path, so that way I will be able to make it work.

Comment: @AnthonyLiard - OK, one last cut based on a lookup table of old values.

Comment: Your solution work, but not for my case because my files are way too big. But you've been really useful and you deserve the accepted answer, especially when you have this  http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero?userid=3744182

Comment: My solution is below if you are curious.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code in the question is the `XmlNodeList`:it creates a list of object that is link to the `XML` files. So when the files get wipe, `XmlNodeList` means nothing. So, changing this list of XmlNode for a list of `string` to these XPath would work.

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//node()[@type='session']");
List<string> xPathList = new List<string>();
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    xPathList.Add(getXPath(node));
}

dBPathTypeSession.Add(new XmlList("b_session_type", i, xPathList));//table,row,paths
```

Where the getXPath function is something like this:

```
static public string getXPath(XmlNode _xmlNode)
{
    Stack<string> xpath = new Stack<string>();

    while (_xmlNode != null)
    {
        if (_xmlNode as XmlElement != null)
            xpath.Push(_xmlNode.Name);

        _xmlNode = _xmlNode.ParentNode as XmlElement;
    }
    return string.Join("/", xpath.ToArray());
}
```

The writer would modify the `string` to `XMLNode` that will have the link to the good files now.

```
foreach (string path in file.Paths)
{
    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(path);
    if (node.Attributes["type"].Value == "system" && node.Attributes["type"].Value != null)
    {
        node.Attributes["type"].Value = "session";
    }
}
//push to DB
```

The `XmlList` class would need to be change to take List instead of `XmlNodeList`